# Elasticsearch 7.0: filter must_not query error

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch-py 7.0 and elasticsearch server 7.0 on a windows 8 machine.

I have this query:

```
{
    'size': 10000, 
    'query': {
        'bool': {'must_not': {'filter': [{'term': {'status': 'ok'}}]}
        }
    }
}
```

The mapping is this:

```
  "mappings": {
      "properties": {
         "name": {"type": "text"},
         "status": {"type": "keyword"},
         "date": {"type":"date"}
      }
    }
```

It follows the rules specified in the [docs for boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) but it doesn't work because it throws a syntax error:

> RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'no [query] registered for [filter]')

However, if I remove the "must_not" element, it works:

```
{
    'size': 10000, 
    'query': {
        'bool': {'filter': [{'term': {'status': 'ok'}}]}
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **`filter`**
>
> The clause (query) must appear in matching documents. However unlike
>   must the score of the query will be ignored. Filter clauses are
>   executed in filter context, meaning that scoring is ignored and
>   clauses are considered for caching.
>
> **`must_not`**
>
> The clause (query) must not appear in the matching documents. Clauses
>   are executed in filter context meaning that scoring is ignored and
>   clauses are considered for caching. Because scoring is ignored, a
>   score of 0 for all documents is returned.

Both `filter` and `must_not` are clauses of the `bool` query and work in the same way. To use `must_not` then you need to remove `filter`:

```js
{
  'size': 10000,
  'query': {
    'bool': {
      'must_not': {
        'term': {
          'status': 'ok'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```